# Faster alternatives to UIWebView/Javascript bridge?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an app that executes JavaScript with a UIWebView (not added to the view hierarchy), but I was wondering what I could do to make it faster. I looked at running node.js with JXcore but it looks like that isn't going to be supported anymore. WKWebView and JavaScriptCore don't appear to have any sync functionality, and we need that for the app. I've even tried enabling gestures while the app executes the JavaScript so that at least the user can navigate during the call, but the main thread is being blocked (and anything done by a UIWebView has to be on the main thread anyway). Any suggestions for what I can use instead of a UIWebView?

Answer (score 1):

Use the JavaScriptCore framework if your script doesn't rely on DOM object. It has a sync [evaluateScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/JavaScriptCore/Reference/JSContext_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/JSContext/evaluateScript:) method.